# How to make Picasso/Glide work with Html.ImageGetter for caching images?

Tags: android, caching, picasso, android-bitmap, android-glide

**Thanks for all the effort @Budius has made.**

Most part of image work of my app could be handled by Picasso/Glide, however, some images are displayed in a `TextView` by `Html.fromHtml`. And the images in `TextView` are also used frequently.

However, I don't know how to implement `getDrawable()` method with Picasso/Glide for the `ImageGetter` passed to `Html.fromHtml`. Is it possible to share the same cache of Picasso/Glide for these pictures in `TextView` and other bitmaps?

Or should I use an custom `LruCache` instead to cache these pictures form `ImageGetter` separately? Will this way increase the risk of an OOM error? And I think it creates unnecessary workload to use 2 different systems for processing images.

**Update:** I tried to use `.get()` of Picasso, but the doc says

```
/**
 * The result of this operation is not cached in memory because the underlying    
 * {@link Cache} implementation is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.
 */
```

So the cache is not used in this case.

**Update:**
The answer of @Budius is right, but code of setting bounds for the `Drawable` is missing, which leaves the `Drawable` not displayed in the `TextView`. So I modified the code in the `DrawableWrapper` class into:

```
public void setWrappedDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (mDrawable != null) {
        mDrawable.setCallback(null);
    }
    mDrawable = drawable;
    if (drawable != null) {
        mDrawable.setBounds(0,0,mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        drawable.setCallback(this);
    }
}
```

**Update:**, the problem is still unsolved. If you implement the solution forementioned, there are some strange behaviors for the image in `TextView`. Sometimes the image could not be refreshed unless you switch to another app and switch back, and the position of image is severely incorrect.

**Update:** I have post all the code for test below. There're still some bugs. Without a placeholder, it still throws an NPE. With a placeholder, the behavior is very strange. The first time I enter `TestActivity`, it shows the placeholder but it won't change into the downloaded pic. But after I switch to another app or press a back button and enter `TestActivity` again, the pic is displayed(maybe because it's in the cache?).

And also the size of pic is right but the place is still not left for the image. And if I call `mDrawable.setBounds(getBounds());` instead of `mDrawable.setBounds(0,0,getIntrinsicWidth(),getIntrinsicHeight());`, it will not be displayed.

### DrawableWrapper

```
public class DrawableWrapper extends Drawable implements Drawable.Callback {
    private Drawable mDrawable;

    public DrawableWrapper(Drawable drawable) {
        setWrappedDrawable(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return 384;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return 216;
    }
    //... other delegation methods are omitted

    public void setWrappedDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (mDrawable != null) {
            mDrawable.setCallback(null);
        }
        mDrawable = drawable;
        if (drawable != null) {
            mDrawable.setBounds(0,0,getIntrinsicWidth(),getIntrinsicHeight());
            drawable.setCallback(this);
        }
    }
}
```

### PicassoTargetDrawable

```
public class PicassoTargetDrawable extends DrawableWrapper
        implements Target {

    private Context context;

    public PicassoTargetDrawable(Context context) {
        super(new ColorDrawable(0));
        // use application context to not leak activity
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        setWrappedDrawable(errorDrawable);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        setWrappedDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
        context = null;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        setWrappedDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
        invalidateSelf();
    }
}
```

### TestActivity

```
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        setContentView(textView);
        String html = "<div>test<br/>" +
                "<img src=\"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/150910165544-elon-evo-open-still-384x216.png\"></img>" +
                "<br/>/test</div>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html, new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                PicassoTargetDrawable d = new PicassoTargetDrawable(TestActivity.this);
                Picasso.with(TestActivity.this)
                        .load(source)
                        //add placeholder here
                        .into(d);
                return d;
            }
        }, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just make a `BitmapDrawable` from the `Bitmap` you get from Picasso's `Target`?

Comment: I think this is an async process, so it cannot apply to `getDrawable()`. Could you please be more specific about how to code it?

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is to return a wrap drawable. And keep using Picasso to download the image.

On the following link you can find an DrawableWrapper, it's from Googles support library, but it's not part of the public docs, so I would just copy the whole code into your project https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper.java

And then you create a `PicassoTargetDrawable` from it.

```
public class PicassoTargetDrawable extends DrawableWrapper
        implements Picasso.Target {

    private Context context;

    public PicassoTargetDrawable(Context context) {
        super(new ColorDrawable(0));
        // use application context to not leak activity
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        setWrappedDrawable(errorDrawable);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        setWrappedDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
        context = null;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        setWrappedDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
        invalidateSelf();
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of loading it up

```
public void Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    PicassoTargetDrawable d = new PicassoTargetDrawable(context);
    Picasso.with(context)
       .load(source)
       ..... add here onError and placeholder drawables
       .into(d);
    return d;
}
```

**PS.:**
I wrote all this without looking up too much, there will probably be a few typos and a few issues to sort it out, but it's certainly enough for you to understand the concept.

**update:**
Just correcting your code.

The TextView already told the WrapDrawable the Bounds it should use. If you're telling the new mDrawable that it can use whatever size it wants, it will use whatever size it wants. So instead of passing its own intrinsic width/height, you should pass the size that was give to the WrapDrawable

```
public void setWrappedDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (mDrawable != null) {
       mDrawable.setCallback(null);
    }
    mDrawable = drawable;
    if (drawable != null) {     
        mDrawable.setBounds(getBounds());
        drawable.setCallback(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I call the `Html.fromHtml()` from a background thread, it throws an Exception for the `.into` must be called from the main thread. And when I call it from the UI thread, it throws an NPE for `mDrawable.draw(canvas)` in `DrawableWrapper`.    Code is `Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(html, getImageGetter(), null);
                    textView.setText(text);`

Comment: And if i call `.placeholder()` before `.into()`, then no exception is thrown. But the image is not shown either.

Comment: you must call it from the UI thread. Apparently the `WrapDrawable` doesn't protect agasint `null`, so I've just added a transparent drawable to the `PicassoTargetDrawable` constructor. Check the code again, I just edited it on my answer.

Comment: I updated the code but is still getting the same problem: With placeholder(), it throws no exception but neither placeholder nor the target image are shown. Without it, a NPE is thrown.

Comment: and my test result is that the image has been downloaded successfully however it's not showing.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Placeholder shouldn't make a difference, it should be just a `nice to have`. You'll have to step-debug it yourself. I imagine if you need to supply the size of the image straight away or the TextView rendering the `Spanned` won't re-adjust later.

Comment: I have solved the problem. `mDrawable.setBounds(0,0,mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
` is missing in the `DrawableWrapper` class.

Comment: Sorry that I cancelled the accept, there are some more bugs found. Still thanks.

Comment: on line 51 of the wrap drawable you have the `setBounds` callback. I've been using that code from Google on my project without issues. The only callbacks I've noticed it's missing from there is the `getOutline` for Lollipop to draw shadows.

Comment: Oh, I see on your edited what u meant about the `setBounds`, the WrapDrawabe implementation was not counting for changed drawable midway through. Do you know in advance the size of those images? I mean, if you know the image will be, for example, `32dp`, you could force WrapDrawable (with some constructor parameter) to return that value from `getIntrinsicHeight` and `getIntrinsicWidth`, that should help the TextView to properly pre-allocate space for the drawable within the text. And as I said on my answer, I typed this by heart just to give you the idea.

Comment: I edited my answer, added a correction to your `setBounds` code. Check the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I have post up all my code. And I think I can get the size of some images. I will try it. There's still a bug, plz see my update.